# Creating chart as GIF and load onto UserForm

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm using John Walkenbach code to export a chart as a GIF and then load it onto a user form. The problem I'm having is With this bit here `Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(Fname)`. It is not loading the GIF onto the UserForm. It exports the Image fine I can see it in the same directory as my excel file.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call GetChart
    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(Fname)
    MsgBox "Yep"
End Sub

Public Sub GetChart()
    Set CurrentChart = Sheets("StatsDB").ChartObjects(1).Chart
    Fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "/temp.gif"
    CurrentChart.Export Filename:=Fname, FilterName:="GIF"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a value to `Fname` before you use it.  There are several way of doing that:

1) Just assigning the value in `CommandButton1_Click`

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    GetChart
    Fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "/temp.gif"
    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(Fname)
    MsgBox "Yep"
End Sub

Public Sub GetChart()
    Set CurrentChart = Sheets("StatsDB").ChartObjects(1).Chart
    Fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "/temp.gif"
    CurrentChart.Export Filename:=Fname, FilterName:="GIF"
End Sub
```

2) Passing the value you used in `GetChart` back as a "return" value:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Fname = GetChart()
    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(Fname)
    MsgBox "Yep"
End Sub

Public Function GetChart() As String
    Set CurrentChart = Sheets("StatsDB").ChartObjects(1).Chart
    Fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "/temp.gif"
    CurrentChart.Export Filename:=Fname, FilterName:="GIF"
    GetChart = Fname
End Sub
```

3) Making `Fname` module-level in scope:

```
Dim Fname As String

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    GetChart
    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(Fname)
    MsgBox "Yep"
End Sub

Public Sub GetChart()
    Set CurrentChart = Sheets("StatsDB").ChartObjects(1).Chart
    Fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "/temp.gif"
    CurrentChart.Export Filename:=Fname, FilterName:="GIF"
End Sub
```

4) Combining the two subroutines into one:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Set CurrentChart = Sheets("StatsDB").ChartObjects(1).Chart
    Fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "/temp.gif"
    CurrentChart.Export Filename:=Fname, FilterName:="GIF"
    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(Fname)
    MsgBox "Yep"
End Sub
```

There would be lots more ways of doing this, but hopefully one of the above appeals to you.

Comment: I ended up using 1) But I didn't know you you could do it like 2). I will probably us it instead and there is a load of other applications for it which is nice.